# gdb backtrace mechanism

Tags: gdb, backtrace

The mechanism that allows `gdb` to perform `backtrace 1` is well explained.

- Starting from the current frame, look at the return address
- Look for a function whose code section contains that address.

Theoretically, there might be hundreds of thousands of functions to consider.
I was wondering if there are any inherent limitations that prevent `gdb`
from creating a lookup table with `return address -> function name`.

Answer (score 2):

> The mechanism that allows gdb to perform backtrace 1 is well explained.

This isn't *at all* how GDB performs a `backtrace`.

The address stored in the `rip` register points to the *current* instruction, and has *nothing* to do with return address.

The return address is stored on the stack, or possibly in another register. To find *where* it is stored (on `x86_64`, and assuming e.g. Linux/ELF/DWARF file format), GDB looks up unwind descriptor that covers the current value of `RIP`. The unwind descriptor also tells GDB how to restore other registers to the state they were just before the current function was called.

You can see unwind descriptors with e.g. `readelf -wf a.out` command.

Once GDB knows how to find return address and restore registers, it can effectively perform an `up` command, stepping from current (called) frame into previous (caller) frame.

Now this process repeats, until either GDB finds a special unwind descriptor which says "I am the last, don't try to unwind past me", or some error occurs (e.g. restored `RIP` is `0`).

Notably, *nowhere* in this process does GDB have to consider thousands of functions.

Comment: Sorry for the inaccuracies -- I removed the wrong part about `rip`. Still, where is the association between the return address and the calling function's name?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom absolutely, if you want to print the name of the calling function you need to map from an address to a name.  What makes you think GDB doesn't already use (semi-)efficient data structures to do this mapping?

Comment: @Andrew, just to confirm: gdb's backtrace is inherently **not an O(1) operation**. But, it is **not an O(n) operation too** because it uses some kind of efficient data structure and does not really inspect all function addresses in the executable (?)

Comment: @OrenIshShalom I think I would agree with that statement.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think GDB does a straight search through all functions?  This isn't what happens.  GDB organises symbols into a couple of different data structures that allow for more efficient mapping between addresses and the enclosing function.

A good place to start might be here: https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/blockframe.c;h=d9c28e0a0176a1d91fec1df089fdc4aa382e8672;hb=HEAD#l118